# Running program again and storing result in an array

Tags: c++

this is my program here for matching sub strings. I want to change the way input and output works in my program.

#### Problem Definition:

- The user is prompted for how many strings they will input (N)
- N strings will be input on separate lines
- For each string,
- Print 1 if it begins with "hackerrank"
- Print 2 if it ends with "hackerrank"
- Print 0 if it starts and ends with "hackerrank"
- Print -1 if none of the above

#### Example:

Input:

```
4
i love hackerrank
hackerrank is an awesome place for programmers
hackerrank
i think hackerrank is a great place to hangout



Output:
2
1
0
-1
```

This is my actual code.

```
int main()
{

    vector<string> token_store;
    string s,token;



    getline(cin,s);
    std::istringstream iss(s);


    while(iss>>token)
        token_store.push_back(token);   //splitting strings into tokens


    int len=token_store.size();        //storing size of vector

    if(token_store[0]=="hack" && token_store[len-1]=="hack")
       cout<<"first and last same";     //if first and last word of input string is hack
    else if(token_store[0]=="hack")
       cout<<"first matches";                                    //if first word of input string is hack
    else if(token_store[len-1]=="hack")
       cout<<"last matches";                                 //if last word of input string is hack

}
```

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble? Are you having trouble reading "4" as a number? Do you want `token_store` to be an array instead of a vector? Do you want to iterate over the vector and send the tokens to `cout`? What is the logic behind the "2, 1, 0, -1"?

Comment: @ Beta I'll try to be more clear.First ask user how many strings he want to check.Let's say 3.Then he writes strings one by one and the code acts on those strings and stores the result of first string in an array and of second string in the same array and so on and finally displaying that array as the output.

Comment: And P.S I haven't implemented this on the above code and asking how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will read input and check for the string "hackerrank"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> token_store;
    int amount;
    string s;

    cin >> amount;
    cin.ignore();

    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        getline(cin, s);
    token_store.push_back(s);
    }

    string match = "hackerrank";

for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
    bool starts = false;
    bool ends = false;
    string str = token_store[i];

    if(str.length() < match.length()){
        std::cout << -1 << "\n";
        continue;
    }
    starts = str.substr(0, match.length()) == match; // Check if string starts with match
    ends = str.substr(str.length()-match.length()) == match; // Check if string ends with match

    if(starts && ends)
        std::cout << 0 << "\n";
    else if(starts)
        std::cout << 1 << "\n";
    else if(ends)
        std::cout << 2 << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << -1 << "\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I asked for and I apologise for not being clear .The output here is the string which prints after matching the substring.

Comment: Here's the question if it helps.Please ignore the regex part.I am trying to use some other method here.


 https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-hackerrank

Comment: I changed the code to also print the solution.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        getline(cin, s);
    token_store.push_back(s);
    }`
    How will this work?Isn't it storing all of the sentences that user will input in a single vector `token_store`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does. This vector will keep a list of all strings and for every line, the code will add a string to this vector.

Comment: But foe example I type 2 strings `I love hackerrank` and `hackerrank is what I love` so the vector will contain concatenation of these two strings which is not what the program wants.This is what I infer from it and I know I am missing something here as your program works perfectly.

Comment: The `push_back` function doesn't concatenate the two strings. Think of a vector as an array which can grow in size. This vector stores a string each time the function `push_back` is called.

Comment: Oh yes..It was a vector of strings.Thank you for walking me through it and chose this as the right answer.

Comment: And I was wondering what if instead of strings user inputs an array of integers and I have to find something for each array and then display the result like the above case.Do I have to use a vector of vectors?I can work on a single array but when it comes to taking multiple inputs and then displaying the answer I just reach a dead end.